# Sending data back to UI thread asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

Currently i am doing a project that involved the page navigation control by Window Workflow Foundation 4. I able to achieve this by block the UI thread until the WF thread returned back the url.

But this is not pratical as well , if my WF stuff is having a long processing time , then the UI thread will be stopped for a certain time and users are not realize about that.

Any guide that i can return my url/page data asynchronously from WF4 and catch on the UI.

Comment: did you try async handler ?

Comment: no, PKKG. Unfortunately i am using vs2010 with .Net 4 only. I'm looking into Shaamaan suggestion. Feel free to receive any further suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options, but all revolve around creating a multi-threaded application.

The easiest* approach, I think, is to use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class ([usage example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

Other options include using the `async` and `await` keywords available in .NET 4.5 (if you are using this version of dotNET). If you're using older version and don't want to use `BackgroundWorker`, you can use the `Task` class for creating background tasks. An even more primitive method involves using and managing `Thread` instances (if the `Task` class is not available). Seeing as you're using WF 4, some of the newer techniques should work just fine. ;)

One thing to note, which most people starting off with multi-threading forget (been there, done that) - you cannot access resources belonging to the UI thread (the main thread of your app) from another thread! This is why the `BackgroundWorker` might be a nice solution for starting, as it exposes 2 events (`ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted`) which allow you to perform stuff on the UI as needed.

* - by easiest I mean easiest to start with! For example `async`/`await` are better suited for an application which needs to perform lots of different async operations, but then again those aren't all that easy until you get the hang of multi-threading in general.

Actually, you didn't specify how many async operations your application will perform and you mentioned being restricted by .NET 4.0 (so no `async` / `await`). If you need to perform a lot of different operations I'd recommend making use of the `Task` class.

With a bit of effort you can use tasks to create a working, multi-threaded application without resorting to creating spaghetti-code, which can be a real nightmare. This is especially useful when you're stuck using `Begin-End` async methods in your services - `Task.Factory.FromAsync` can be REALLY helpful in this case. Event driven async services should also expose an interface which uses `Begin-End`.